# how do i create a path between 2 bitmaps

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

Hello I was wondering how can I make 2 bitmaps in which the second one comes out of the first one, moving to a different place while and leaving behind him a drawn path like in the game "Osu", [like this](http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/3/30523/1425172-osu__hit_circle_slider.png]).

Comment: i would render a sequence of them. the standard question on se is what have you tried so far?

Comment: What technology do you use? OpenGL? Unity? You should provide more information about your project status for a better responses.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and so far I only have only 1 circle which changed his bitmap x,y when the crusor is inside it..what are my options?